# Trying to verify the accuracy of a Stanley Milgram paraphrase

Tags: social-psychology, experimental-psychology

I searched the Internet in an attempt to verify but all hits were secondary or lesser sources.  Could someone point me to an original source?

"Psychologist Stanley Milgram found that 80% of people do not have the psychological and moral resources to defy an authority's order, no matter how legitimate the order is. Only 20% have critical capacity."

Comment: Note that the [Milgram Experiment](https://doi.org/10.1177%2F0098628316677644) has been widely discredited, so whatever finding he actually made is irrelevant anyway.

Comment: "Note that the Milgram Experiment has been widely discredited"    

While that may well be(I'm no expert, hence the question) the experiment is still discussed and per Wikipedia: "He is widely regarded as one of the most important figures in the history of social psychology. A Review of General Psychology survey, published in 2002, ranked Milgram as the 46th-most-cited psychologist of the 20th century."   

That being the case, is paraphrase I originally posted accurate to Milgram's writings and a bonus would be is there any extra-Milgram support for the statement?